# awk: ignore the comment in file

Tags: awk

i'm doing a awk homework
and get the file IN-arg

```
      # this is a comment
      joejoejoe 10 20 30 #this is also a comment
      OAK -999 10 # 10000
      joeJOE 2000
      oak 10
      milk 1000 # 2000
```

and I want to ignore the comment in the file IN-arg
and get something like this

```
      joejoejoe 10 20 30 
      OAK -999 10 
      joeJOE 2000
      oak 10
      milk 1000
```

how can i do it

below is my code

```
#! /bin/awk -f

{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
  {
    if($i == "#")
      i = NF + 1
    print $i
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

What about changing the field separator to `#` and printing `$1` (first field) when it is not empty?

Give this a try:

```
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN { FS="#" }
$1 ~ /./ { print $1 }
```

Comment: If you change the FS to `"[[:spaces:]]*#"` then it'd also not leave trailing spaces (which may or may not be desirable).

Answer (score 1):

Using any POSIX awk:

```
$ awk '$1 !~ /^#/{sub(/[[:space:]]*#.*/,""); print}' 'IN-arg'
      joejoejoe 10 20 30
      OAK -999 10
      joeJOE 2000
      oak 10
      milk 1000
```

I'm assuming above that you don't **really** want to leave trailing white space when comments are removed from the end of lines but if you do then remove `[[:space:]]*` from the command.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '
      # this is a comment
      joejoejoe 10 20 30 #this is also a comment
      OAK -999 10 # 10000
      joeJOE 2000
      oak 10
      milk 1000 # 2000' |
```

---

```
awk 'NF = $1 !~ "^[ \t-\r]*$"' FS='#.*'
```

---

```
 1        joejoejoe 10 20 30 
 2        OAK -999 10 
 3        joeJOE 2000
 4        oak 10
 5        milk 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '!/#/ || !/^ *#/ && gsub(/ *#.*$/,"")'  file 
      joejoejoe 10 20 30
      OAK -999 10
      joeJOE 2000
      oak 10
      milk 1000
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on how the proposed solution solves the problem and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to choose GNU Awk for the task, which supports a regular expression in the `RS` (record separator variable), a nice way to do this is:

```
$ echo 'line1 # comment
line2 # comment
# line3
line4 #comment
line5' | awk -v RS='(#[^\\n]*)?\\n' '{ printf("rec[%d] = %s\n", NR, $0) }'
rec[1] = line1
rec[2] = line2
rec[3] =
rec[4] = line4
rec[5] = line5
```

We include the end-of-line comment in the record separator, so it disappears at the low level, when GNU Awk is delimiting the input into records.

Our record separator is "optional hash comment, followed by newline", where the optional hash comment is "hash mark, followed by any number of non-newline characters".

POSIX says that the behavior is unspecified if `RS` is given a value that is more than one character long; POSIX doesn't support regular expressions in `RS`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /bin/awk -f

{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
  {
    if($i == "#")
      i = NF + 1
    print $i
  }
}
```

This would not work as intended as you `print` each field, you would get newline after each field, you can use `printf` to avoid that, also as you allows comment like `#this is also a comment` then `#` does not to have be separate field whilst using default field separator of one-or-more white-space characters. If you want to have each character as field set `FPAT` built-in variable to `.`, you might also use `break` to end loop rather than tinkering with variable used in condition. You also need to ignore line where there is only comment - or in other words only print anything for lines which are not starting with white-space characters and `#`.

After applying these changes your code would become

```
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN{FPAT="."}
!/^[[:space:]]*#/{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
  {
    if($i == "#")
      break
    printf "%s",$i
  }
  print ""
}
```

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*